# Rails rspec trying to redirect to /users/sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write Rspec tests to make sure that if there isn't an admin signed in, then the user can't create an invitation and then gets redirected back to the sign_in page

```
describe 'GET index', focus: true do
    context 'with an admin user signed in' do
      with :admin
      let!(:invitation) { create :invitation }

      before do
        sign_in admin
        get :index
      end
      it { should respond_with :ok }
      it { should respond_with_content_type :html }
      it { should render_template :index }
      it 'assigns all invitations as @invitations' do
        expect(assigns(:invitations)).to eq([invitation])
      end
    end
    context 'with a non-admin user signed in' do
      with :user
      before do
        sign_in user
        get :index
      end
      it {should redirect_to new_user_session_path }
    end
  end
```

Something with the redirect isn't working, though. This is the failure I'm getting:

```
1) InvitationsController GET index with a non-admin user signed in should redirect to "/users/sign_in"
     Failure/Error: it {should redirect_to new_user_session_path }
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/>.
       Expected "http://test.host/users/sign_in" to be === "http://test.host/".
     # ./spec/controllers/invitations_controller_spec.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And I'm not really sure how to address it. I'm learning Rails at the moment, so I apologize if the answer is obvious. Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think my problem was that I was redirecting to the wrong path. I changed it to root_path and that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise's new user sign in page detects that your user is already logged on, so it redirects your user to the front page.

If you really want the user to get logged out when trying to access the invitations controller without being an admin, then you should force a log out in your failed authorization handler.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your rails console with `rails c` and type `rake routes`.

You should get a list of all the routes in your application as well as their prefixes which are suffixed with `_path` when doing a redirect.

For instance:

`Prefix            Verb       URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
new_user_session   GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new`

If this route doesn't exist then you will have to create it in order for the test to pass.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it exists.